# Preserve directory structure when moving files using find

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename

I have created the following script that move old days  files as defined  from source directory to destination directory. It is working perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Your Source Directory"
read soure

echo "Enter Your Destination Directory"
read destination 

echo "Enter Days"
read days



 find "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec mv {} "$destination" \;

  echo "Files which were $days Days old moved from $soure to $destination"
```

This script moves files great, It also move files of source subdirectory, but it doesn't create subdirectory into destination directory. I want to implement this  additional feature in it.

with example

```
/home/ketan     : source directory

/home/ketan/hex : source subdirectory

/home/maxi      : destination directory
```

When I run this script , it also move hex's files in maxi directory, but I need that same hex should be created into maxi directory and move its files in same hex there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of running `mv /home/ketan/hex/foo /home/maxi`, you'll need to vary the target directory based on the path produced by `find`. This is easier if you change to the source directory first and run `find .`. Now you can merely prepend the destination directory to each item produced by `find`. You'll need to run a shell in the `find … -exec` command to perform the concatenation, and to create the target directory if necessary.

```
destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd) # make it an absolute path
cd -- "$source" &&
find . -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec sh -c '
  mkdir -p "$0/${1%/*}"
  mv "$1" "$0/$1"
' "$destination" {} \;
```

Note that to avoid quoting issues if `$destination` contains special characters, you can't just substitute it inside the shell script. You can export it to the environment so that it reaches the inner shell, or you can pass it as an argument (that's what I did). You might save a bit of execution time by grouping `sh` calls:

```
destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd) # make it an absolute path
cd -- "$source" &&
find . -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec sh -c '
  for x do
    mkdir -p "$0/${x%/*}"
    mv "$x" "$0/$x"
  done
' "$destination" {} +
```

Alternatively, in zsh, you can use the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv), and the `.` and `m` [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to only match regular files in the right date range. You'll need to pass an alternate `mv` function that first creates the target directory if necessary.

```
autoload -U zmv
mkdir_mv () {
  mkdir -p -- $3:h
  mv -- $2 $3
}
zmv -Qw -p mkdir_mv $source/'**/*(.m-'$days')' '$destination/$1$2'
```

Comment: `for x do`, you've got a missing `;` there :). Also, I have no idea what you wanted to achieve with `$0` but I'm quite convinced it would be `sh` :).

Comment: @MichałGórny `for x; do` is technically not POSIX-compliant (check the [grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02)), but modern shells allow both `for x do` and `for x; do`; some old Bourne shells didn't grok `for x; do`. On modern shells, with `sh -c '…' arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3`, `arg0` becomes `$0`, `arg1` becomes `$1`, etc. If you want `$0` to be `sh`, you need to write `sh -c '…' sh arg1 arg2 arg3`. Again, some Bourne shells behaved differently, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) specifies this.

Comment: `pushd` seems like a better choice that `cd`, as it less intrusive into the current environment.

Comment: This command creates directories for complete path, that is it creates a directory for the matching file as well. I wish to copy directory structure only upto the matching file.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', thanks, this is very useful
btw, i used `sed -i.bak` for many files, i want to move those `.bak` files to another backup folder, by using your script, all `.bak` files moved to my back folder successfully
how can i change the script to remove `.bak`  in file name, so in backup folder, filename is same as original one?

Comment: @jerry `zmv '(*).bak' '$1'` or `zmv '*.bak' '$f:r'`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', thanks for the update, i'm using ubuntu 18.04 lts, there's no `zmv` by default, is it possible to use bash to achieve that?

Comment: @jerry Sure, it's just more complicated. This has been covered many times on this site. Please search questions tagged [tag:rename].

Answer (score 39):

I know `find` was specified, but this sounds like a job for `rsync`.

**Examples**

Mirror files with same directory structure (source remains in tact):

```
rsync -axuv --progress Source/ Target/
```

Move files with same directory structure (removing from source and removing empty directories):

```
rsync -axuv --prune-empty-dirs --remove-source-files --progress Source/ Target/
```

Move files of a particular file-type ([example](https://silentorbit.com/notes/2013/rsync-by-extension/)):

```
rsync -rv --include '*/' --include '*.js' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs Source/ Target/
```

Move files resulting from an advanced `find` search:

```
cd "$source" &&
  rsync -av --remove-source-files --prune-empty-dirs --progress --files-from <(find . -type f -mtime -$days) . "$destination"
```

**A note about file removal**

There are options for `rsync` that can ensure your destination directory mirrors your source directory, which then remove files in the destination that are no longer in your source (i.e. `--delete-before`, `--delete-after`, `--delete-during`, and `--delete-delay`.

You can also allow removing files from the source directory when they have been moved from the destination directory, i.e. `--remove-source-files`.

This is use case dependent, so how you handle that is up to you.

*Note:* As Sridar Sarnobat points out, if you rsync a a directory with symlinks to the directory you are rsync'ing to, *and* pass --remove-source-files`, you could end up with data loss.

Comment: much cleaner than the others solutions :)

Comment: I found that `--remove-source-files` was helpful, which effectively causes files to be moved instead of copied. This is an awesome use of rsync.

Comment: The only problem I see in this approach is that I did not find a way to specify a date or a time window for rsync to consider (e.g., move files older than 3 months).

Comment: @LuisTalora You could try using [--include-from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706362/943773) combined with a find search piped to a grep that filters by timestamp.

Comment: Be careful with symbolic links. If you `rsync --remove-source-files A/ B/` and B is a symlink to A, you'll delete everything in A. It's happened to me every 12 months or so.

Comment: Interesting point. That has never happened to me, but it is possible to ignore symlinks with the `--no-links` option as well.

Answer (score 4):

you could do it using two instances of find(1)

There's always cpio(1)

```
(cd "$soure" && find … | cpio -pdVmu "$destination")
```

Check the arguments for cpio. The ones I gave

Comment: This will break on any filenames with whitespace.

Comment: This copies files instead of moving them.

Comment: May not be a perfect answer, but it helped me to move files preserving paths in a more or less straight forward manner (I have enough space to copy the files then delete). Upvoted

Answer (score 4):

It's not as efficient, but the code is easier to read and understand, in my opinion, if you just copy the files and then delete afterwards.

```sh
find /original/file/path/* -mtime +7 -exec cp {} /new/file/path/ \;
find /original/file/path/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

**Notice: Flaw discovered by @MV for automated operations:**

> Using two separate operations is risky. If some files become older than 7 days 
>   while the copy operation is done, they won't be copied but they will be deleted 
>   by the delete operation. For something being done manually once this may not be 
>   an issue, but for automated scripts this may lead to data loss

Comment: Using two separate operations is risky. If some files become older than 7 days while the copy operation is done, they won't be copied but they will be deleted by the delete operation. For something being done manually once this may not be an issue, but for automated scripts this may lead to data loss.

Comment: The easy solution to this flaw is to run find once, save the list as a text file, and then use xargs twice to do the copy and then the delete.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by appending the absolute path of the file returned by `find` to your destination path:

```
find "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c '
    file="{}"
    destination="'"$destination"'"
    mkdir -p "$destination/${file%/*}"
    mv "$file" "$destination/$file"'
```

Comment: Chris now its moves whole home into maxi

Comment: @K.KPatel No, it doesn't. It merely keeps your directory structure.

Comment: This breaks if `$destination` contains special characters, because it undergoes expansion in the inner shell. Maybe you meant `destination='\'"$destination"\''`? That still breaks on `'`. Also, this creates files such as `/home/maxi/home/ketan/hex/foo` instead of `/home/maxi/hex/foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Better (fastest & without consuming storage space by doing copy instead of move), also is not affected by the file-names if they contain special characters in their names:

```
export destination
find "$soure" -type f "-$days" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 bash -c '
for file in "$@"; do
  echo -n "Moving $file to $destination/"`dirname "$file"`" ... "
  mkdir -p "$destination"/`dirname "$file"`
  \mv -f "$file" "$destination"/`dirname "$file"`/ || echo " fail !" && echo "done."
done'
```

Or faster, moving a bunch of files in the same time for multi-CPU, using the "parallel" command:

```
echo "Move oldest $days files from $soure to $destination in parallel (each 10 files by "`parallel --number-of-cores`" jobs):"
function move_files {
  for file in "$@"; do
    echo -n "Moving $file to $destination/"`dirname "$file"`" ... "
    mkdir -p "$destination"/`dirname "$file"`
    \mv -f "$file" "$destination"/`dirname "$file"`/ || echo " fail !" && echo "done."
  done
}
export -f move_files
export destination
find "$soure" -type f "-$days" -print0 | parallel -0 -n 10 move_files
```

P.S.: You have a typo, "soure" should be "source". I kept the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

This is less elegant but easy if the number / size of files isn't too great

Zip your files together into a `zip` archive, and then unzip at the destination without the `-j` option. By default, zip will create the relative directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

I am using it this way

```
cp -r source/ destination/
find destination/ -not -path "*/mypattern/*.py" -delete
```

Basically copy everything from source to destination and delete everythings other than the required stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been using, with find, tar, and rm. Replace find arguments with arguments you would need, but retain the `-type f`, files only option.

```
cd srcdir        # OR pushd srcdir

find . -mtime +7 -type f |  while read fn; do echo Moving $fn; tar cf - "$fn" | ( cd destdir; tar xf - );  rm -f "$fn"; done

# popd
```

(Skip the "echo Moving $fn" command to execute the job silently.)
The above method may leave empty directories in the source tree. One could use

```
find srcdir -empty -type d -delete
```

to remove empty directories.

Answer (score -1):

Because there seem to be no really easy solution to this and I need it very often, I created this open source utility for linux (requires python): https://github.com/benapetr/smv

There are multiple ways how you could use it to achieve what you need but probably most simple would be something like this:

```
 # -vf = verbose + force (doesn't stop on errors)
smv -vf `find some_folder -type f -mtime "-$days"` target_folder
```

You can additionally run it in dry mode so that it doesn't do anything but print what it would do

```
smv -rvf `find some_folder -type f -mtime "-$days"` target_folder
```

Or in case that list of files is too long to fit into argument line and you don't mind executing python for every single file, then

```
find "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec smv {} "$destination" \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `find "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days"`;
do
  mkdir -p "$destination"/`dirname $f`;
  mv $f "$destination"/`dirname $f`;
done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# '+' here shows that 'find' looking for files 45 and more days older from NOW
# can be replaced with '-' (-45), to search for files with modification date from NOW to 45 days(max)
days='+45'

source=/var/log

destination=/root/logsbackups

# searching can take some time, so inform user/script what is happening
echo "\nSearching for files..."

# collecting files list as Array to variable
LIST_OF_FILES=(`find $source -type f -mtime $days`)

echo "Moving files..."

# process collected file paths Array for proper moving
for file in ${LIST_OF_FILES[@]}; do

  # real full path to file (without filename)
  filepath=$(dirname $file)
  
  # full file name (without path)
  filename=$(basename $file)

  # log info (unnecessary)
  echo "Moving to $destination$filepath$filename"
  
  # make sure that target directory exists
  mkdir -p $destination$filepath
  
  # moving file
  mv -f $file $destination$filepath$filename

done
```

Comment: Consider testing this on a collection of files with names containing spaces and filename globbing characters. Since you don't quote _any_ of your expansions, the shell would perform splitting and filename globbing on the output of `find`, and then again later when you fail to quote `$file`, `$filepath` and `$filename`.

Comment: @Kusalananda good point. But still works for me. Tested on Debian, and right now works for transfer mail files (300K) on CentOS virtual server with limited (10GB) storage space. You still can suggest more elegant and idiot proof code.

Comment: (1) With all due respect, nobody cares if the script is working ***for you*** using ***your** filenames,* which are all-alphanumeric (`foo`, `bar`, `ds9`, etc.) There’s no way ``LIST_OF_FILES=(`find $source  -type f  …`)`` works correctly for all filenames (or even a tricky value for ```$source```).  (2) We don’t like code-only answers.  Please explain what you are doing (and how it is different from previous answers).  (3) See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216)

Comment: @g-man-says-reinstate-monica with all due respect, speak for yourself. Where those 'we' are? I do not care about, your personal opinion, for my way to share real, working, and ___finished code___, what can be used with minor changes, not like most sketches, in internet in general, or on this page particular. I am not ___forcing___ any one to use it, but I am guessing - if i had to make such script, and google some of it parts, it can be useful for _someone_, who not picky as 'WE-GROUP-PEOPLE'. About 'loop-in-find-result': for every task - use proper tools. Don't overcomplicate, please.