# Read a list of files from text file, move them preserving directory structure in bash

Tags: bash, centos, mv

Similar to the question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/preserve-directory-structure-when-moving-files-using-find), I'm trying to move a list of files from one folder to another whilst preserving the directory structure. The move command happens after a chain of events earlier in the bash script.

In the linked example, the mv command happens on the fly (in a separate C shell?) while the script is doing its finding. This will not work for me, as I need to process the files in the list through an AV scan first. Once they have passed the AV scan, I then want to move them to their destination, preserving directory structure.

My original solution was

```
while read moveitems; do
  printf "mv \"$moveitems\" \"$hotfolder\"\n"
done <"$filesin" | tee -a "filemoves" >/dev/null
chmod +x $filemoves
$filemoves >> $scanlog
```

Which only worked as far as moving all files into a single folder, which isn't suitable for this situation.

I'm sure there are many more elegant, efficient solutions to this problem, unfortunately I'm a right-brain person and this kind of thing doesn't come easy to me. Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mention all the filenames in file. Below mention command will move all the filenames to target directory:

```
awk '{print "mv " " " $1  " " "/Destinationpath"}' filename|sh
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as my original script, in that the directory structure is not maintained and everything is dumped into a single folder. Also it can't handle whitespace in filenames.