# Escaping special characters in parameter expansion

Tags: shell-script, zsh

```
file=/tmp/text/foo.txt
```

Now I want to add a subfolder `/bar` in this directory structure using parameter expansion syntax.
This line works:

```
echo "${file%/*}/bar/${file##*/}"
```

Now I'm wondering if I can make it even shorter with `${parameter/%pat/string}` syntax. I'd like to make `/` as the `pat`, and replace it with `/bar/`. But I don't know how to tell the system which `/` is the pat part. I tried to escape it with `\`, but it didn't work.
The code I wrote is:

```
echo "${f/%///bar/}"
```

or

```
echo "${f/%\///bar/}"
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: If you're going to use this to move files, look at zmv: `zmv '(**/)(*.txt)' '${1}bar/${2}'`. More details, including how to create destination directories with `zmv`, in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59159/432774).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [history modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).

```
for file in /tmp/text/foo.txt /foo.txt foo.txt mydir/; do
  echo $file:h/bar/$file:t
done
```

Note that this gives a correct result except for files in the root directory on systems where `//some/where` is different from `/some/where`. In particular, it works if `$file` doesn't have a directory part at all, whereas the naive version with `${file%/*}` doesn't. If `$file` ends with a slash, `bar` is inserted before the last nonempty path component, which may or may not be what you want.

With the `${VARIABLE/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` parameter expansion form, you can use the [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `I` to select the nth match, but unfortunately you can't select from the end. So `echo ${(I:3:)file/\///bar/}` works in this specific case, but it requires knowing exactly how many levels of directory they are. You can count them:

```
echo ${(I:${#file//[^\/]/}:)file/\///bar/}
```

But that's more complicated than splitting into parts, and it doesn't work any better if there's no slash in `$file`.

With `extended_glob` turned on, you can use the `b` [globbing flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags) in the pattern, and that lets you match the trailing non-slash characters (thanks to the `#` [glob operator](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators)) and use `$match` to refer to the part matched by wildcards.

```
setopt extended_glob
for file in /tmp/text/foo.txt /foo.txt foo.txt mydir/; do
  echo ${file/%(#b)([^\/]#)/bar/$match[1]}
done
```

The pattern is `(#b)([^\/]#)`, matching the trailing non-slash characters and saving the matched part in `$match[1]`. With zsh ≥5.9, you can write `${(*)file/%(#b)([^\/]#)/bar/$match[1]}` and it'll work even if `extended_glob` is off. This is not simple, but it has the advantage of robustness: the result is correct even for the common case of a file name with no directory part and the edge case of a file in a root directory. It yields `mydir/bar/` if `$file` ends with a slash, which may or may not be what you want.